# Telerik MVC Grid with multiple checkboxes in a single row, single column

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik, telerik-grid

I am trying to construct a Telerik MVC grid and am having great difficulty constructing a row which contains more than one checkbox in a grid cell.

So far my attempt has gotten me only half way there. It displays a single row with a whole bunch of check boxes in the first cell, but when I want to add a record via the "Insert" toolbar button, I get a blank line.

Here is my model and view. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class MyModel {

        public MappingsModel[] Mappings { get; set; }

        public class MappingsModel {

            public CustomerRoleModel[] CustomerRoles { get; set; }

            public int[] SelectedCustomerRoleIds { get; set; }
        }

        public class CustomerRoleModel {

            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public bool Selected { get; set; }
        }
    }

@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.Mappings)
                    .Name("rules-grid")
                       .DataKeys(keys =>
                       {
                           keys.Add(x => x.Id);
                       })
                       .DataBinding(dataBinding =>{
                                        dataBinding.Ajax()
                                            .Select("RuleList",   "MyController")
                                            .Insert("RuleInsert", "MyController")
                                            .Update("RuleUpdate", "MyController")
                                            .Delete("RuleDelete", "MyController");
                                    })
                       .Columns(columns =>
                       {
                           columns.Bound(x => x.CustomerRoles)
                                    .Template(@<text>
                                             @foreach (var role in @item.CustomerRoles) {

                                                 <text><input type="checkbox" value="@(role.Id)" id="role_@(role.Id)" name="SelectedCustomerRoleIds" disabled="disabled" </text>

                                                 if(role.Selected) {
                                                      <text>checked="checked"</text>
                                                  }
                                                 <text>/><label for="role_(@role.Id)">@role.Name</label><br /></text>
                                             }
                                         </text>
                                    )
                                    .Width(500);

                           columns.Command(commands =>
                           {
                               commands.Edit();
                               commands.Delete();
                           })
                           .Width(180);
                       })
                       .ToolBar(commands => commands.Insert())
                       .EnableCustomBinding(true));
```

### Update

I have tried the suggestion offered by @howcheng but this renders the checkboxes like so:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

The data I'm getting back via Ajax looks valid even though it doesn't looked correct below. Any ideas?

```
data: [{Name:null, Age:0,…}]
0: {Name:null, Age:0,…}
Age: 0
CustomerRoles: [{Name:Administrators, Selected:false, Id:1}, {Name:Forum Moderators, Selected:false, Id:2},…]
0: {Name:Administrators, Selected:false, Id:1}
1: {Name:Forum Moderators, Selected:false, Id:2}
2: {Name:Guests, Selected:false, Id:4}
3: {Name:Registered, Selected:false, Id:3}
Id: 1
Name: null
total: 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've done is define a display template. In order to edit, you need a custom editor template. Create a partial view in your /Views/Shared/EditorTemplates directory and call it something like "CustomerRoles.cshtml".

Editor template:

```
@model CustomerRoleModel[]
@foreach (CustomerRoleModel crm in Model)
{
  // checkbox code goes here
}
```

Grid code:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.Mappings)
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
    columns.Bound(x => x.CustomerRoles)
      .Template(@<text>
         @item.Select(r => r.Name).Aggregate((s1, s2) => string.Format("{0}, {1}", s1, s2))); // this is for display only
         </text>)
      .ClientTemplate("<#= CustomerRolesClientTemplate(data) #>")
      .EditorTemplateName("CustomerRoles"); // this loads the editor template
    // additional columns
  })
  // additional grid code
)
```

Javascript function for client template:

```
function CustomerRolesClientTemplate(data) {
  var value = '';
  var first = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (!first) value += ', ';
    value += data.Name;
    first = false;
  }
  return value;
}
```

In your Google searching, you might come across [the Telerik documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-display-and-editor-templates.html) -- DON'T RELY ON THIS because it's a little out of date (it's not written for Razor and you don't need to use the `[UIHint]` attribute, for example).

Comment: You're getting [object Object] because your CustomerRoleModel is an object, not a scalar value. Sorry, I didn't realize you were doing AJAX binding as well. For that, you'll need a client template. `.Template()` gives you a server-side display template, whereas `.ClientTemplate()` gives you a client-side display template. Since you're binding to an object, you need a custom function to do the equivalent of the C# server-side code. I have edited my example accordingly.